# Confusion over various webpack shimming approaches

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2, asset-management

I'm a little confused on the various ways webpack allows to expose a variable that isn't available on npm  or to be put in the bundle. I was able to expose the google visualizations chart script's global `google` var by using

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'google': path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor', 'google.js')
    }
  }
```

combined with

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      'google': 'google'
    })
  ]
```

however looking at [the webpack docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules) there a couple other ways to *shim*,  which look like they might do something similar. There is `imports-loader` and `exports-loader`, and `script-loader`. I know that I've linked to the docs, but I still find their descriptions of when these four should be used a bit unclear.

Also looking at this example, is this `require` not assigned to a variable? Where is it meant to go? And where is the documentation on what is going on with this syntax?

```
require("imports?$=jquery!./file.js")
```

#### Can someone provide me some examples of when each of these should be used?

Answer (score 4):

## `scripts-loader`

I never used this myself, but the idea is simple I guess. I think it can be used if for some reason you want to inject a script or a function or something in one of the modules/files you have no control over them.

## `imports-loader` & `exports-loader`

In one of the apps I worked on we had to use [`tinymce`](https://www.tinymce.com/) which in its older versions was dependent on `this` being always `window` because it was built to work as a global script. Not as a CommonJS or ES module.

So in order to fix that, we had to use the `import-loader` so it can inject `window` to the script. Here how it looked like in `webpack.config.js`

```
{ test: require.resolve('tinymce/tinymce'), use: ['imports?this=>window', 'exports?tinymce'] }
```

Which says inject `window` in place of `this` & also we are using `exports-loader` here so we can export the global `tinymce` as a default export named `tinymce` so we can use it as a normal module in our app.

Thankfully all of this is already fixed in the latest releases.

## `ProvidePlugin`

In my experience, this is useful when a library is depending on another library being in a global scope or something. Like jQuery plugins for example, they do use one of these `$`, `window.$`, `jQuery` & `window.jQuery`

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  }),
```

So what this plugin will do is to make sure when `webpack` sees one of these variations it will provide the jQuery object to it instead.

The difference between this & `imports-loader` for example that you might not know which variation is used by which script. So you let `webpack` handle this while the `imports-loader` is kind of more specific.

I hope this helped you a bit to understand the differences between all of them, also this is the new documentation page which I think better than the one you were checking https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

Comment: What's the `!` syntax?

Comment: Webpack adds the option to overload the `require()` function with it's own syntax to allow for using loaders inline. That's why the weird syntax here `require("imports?$=jquery!./file.js")` this is just saying import `$` as `jQuery` for `file.js`

Comment: oh, is that why in the docs it's just `require(....)` not like `const module = require('module')`? can you show an example of this using inline with this syntax please?

Comment: Storing it in a variable or not has nothing to do with the loader, it depends on what you want to do with the `require()`ed or `import`ed script.

This is a very simple one already `require("imports?$=jquery!./file.js")` lets say `file.js` is a jQuery plugin & depends on jQuery as `$` then you are making sure that it gets it gets jQuery as `$`

Comment: You can also check @arturkin example below.

Answer (score 4):

`imports` and `exports` loaders are very simple to understand. If you use one of them, or both, your module is wrapped into another function with exports and imports.

For example, I'm using `paho-mqtt` module meant to be used like global `<script src="">` on the page:

```
import Paho from 'imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?Paho!paho-mqtt';

//and this is transformed by webpack to something like:
(function(window){

    //wow you can use `window here`, `this` in the global context === window.


   // original module code here
   // that exposes global var `Paho`


   module.exports = Paho;

})(this);
```